# TypeScript doesn't pick the right overload type all the times

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Well It's might gonna be a little bit complicated...

So I wanted to create a Component with an 'as' or 'component' property, what **changing** the **root wrapper of the component**. Example:

```
type FlexProps = { flexGrow: ... }
type SomeOtherCompProps = { someOtherProp: ... }

declare function Flex(props: FlexProps): React.ReactElement
declare function SomeOtherComp(props: FlexProps): React.ReactElement

<Box component={Flex} />
```

The declaration of the Box component looks something like this:

```
declare function Box(props: BoxProps & FlexBox): ReactElement
declare function Box<T>(props: BoxProps & { component: React.ComponentType<T> } & T ): ReactElement
```

This means at **default** my Box component should **extend** from **FlexBox**.

```
<Box /> // have { flexGrow } as a properties (at this point its work fine)
```

---

The next lines **for some reason trigger** *(fun, but not at all times..., maybe its picks the first overload if T extending from the Flex component?)* **the first** *(default)* **overload** *(the one with the default Flex component)*

```
<Box component={SomeOtherComp} /> // this should { someOtherProp } as its properties, BUT receive { flexGrow } ...
```

So the question...
Is there an **alternative way**, or a way to **help TS with more hint**, so it's gonna select the **right type** in **all cases**?

**REPRODUCTION:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snow-rwvgb?fontsize=14

Comment: The compiler *generally* picks the first overload that matches without error, but sometimes it does other things (overloads it sees as more "specific").  I don't think I can help answer this particular question without a [mcve] that I can drop into my own IDE (or, ideally, a standalone linkable web IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)).  If you don't get a satisfying answer you might consider editing the code so that it compiles as-is with no external dependencies.  Good luck.

Comment: Make sense, gonna make a demo straight away!

Comment: Sorry was not really available. Makes sense: there is a reproduction example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snow-rwvgb?fontsize=14

Comment: Notice how I am not receiving error if I add a property on on the <Box /> component as: <Box component={TextInput} onChange={() => {}} /> BUT not when the editor do not help at all, and cant see that onChange is available.

Comment: Is there any way to silence the eslint error in line 11?  I'm trying to see past it to understand the issue but it's not fun to have erroneous errors around.

Comment: For some reason // @ts-ignore and tslint:disable-next-line aren't getting respected by the editor. Sorry.

Comment: In your reproduction, could you add code that shows examples of the correct and incorrect overload being chosen and how you know that?  I'm not an expert on jsx; maybe someone else will be able to answer without that information.

Comment: even if I hate it, I can't reproduce when the case where it's working properly. (meaning it's never choosing the right overload)

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand your issue.  Maybe if you edit the code to show exactly what is incorrectly showing an error or incorrectly showing no error, and exactly what you expect to see, I might be able to help.  Otherwise hopefully someone who knows react/jsx better than I do will come along.  Good luck!